# PHP if else - conditional link in form submit button

Tags: php

Hope someone can help put with this - I have inherited a site and am trying to modify some PHP that I am unfamiliar with. I have gotten so far with it, but still have a problem with it.

Its a page on an online store offering optional extras depending on the product. The products are furniture, so and there was an option to buy cushions for some. The change I am trying to make is to have an option for two different sizes of cushion depending on the product.

So there was a field 'cushions' in the product table, and a page 'accessories.php' that offered the option to add cushions.

I have added a new field 'cushions2' and a new page 'accessories2.php' to cover the new size of cushions.

The site is here, with this example product:

http://www.lloydloomonline.com/product.php?id=32

If you click 'Add to cart' the next page offers you the option to add custom paintwork.

If you enter something there, and click on 'Add colour to order' it works - i.e. the next page is the one offering the cushions.

But if you just click on 'No thank you, proceed with order' it just reloads the page - basically the URL isn't being puled through as it should be.

On that page the PHP at the top of the page looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$page = "paintwork";   
include("../includes/header.php");
include("../includes/db_open.php");
$sql =
  "SELECT p.*, c.`name` AS `categoryname` " .
  "FROM `products` p, `categories` c " .
  "WHERE p.`category` = c.`id` " .
  "AND p.`id` = '" . $_SESSION["basket"]["items"][$_REQUEST["id"]]["product"] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed : $sql at line " . __line__);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if (!empty($_POST)) {

$_SESSION["basket"]["items"][$_POST["id"]]["paintwork"] = $_POST["colour"];

if ($row["cushions"] == -1) {
    $url = "accessories.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
} else if ($row["cushions2"] == -1) {
    $url = "accessories2.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
} else if (!empty($row["glasstop"])) {
    $url = "glasstop.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
} else {
    $url = "shopping_cart.php";
}
?>
```

And the form with the input / submit looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
<label for="quantity" style="float: left; width: 75px; margin: 0">COLOUR</label>
<textarea name="colour" id="colour" style="float: left; height: 80px; width: 250px"></textarea>
<img src="images/spacer.gif" class="clear" style="height: 10px" />
<input type="submit" value="ADD COLOUR TO ORDER" id="submit" onmouseover="this.style.color = '#DBC87B'" onmouseout="this.style.color = '#FFFFFF'" style="float: left; margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 10px; width: 255px; padding-bottom: 3px; height: 23px" />
 <a href="<?php echo $url?>" style="float: left; color: #251717; background-color: #DBC87B">NO    THANKYOU, PROCEED WITH ORDER</a>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["id"]?>" />
 </form>
```

Hope that makes sense - I think it must nearly be there, as all the conditional code seems to work, but the URL isn't being pulled through correctly in the form.

If anyone could have a look and hopefully get megabuck on track, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you.

---

The original was a little different, which just had one option for the cushions:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
if (!@empty($_POST)) {
$_SESSION["basket"]["items"][$_POST["id"]]["paintwork"] = $_POST["colour"];
if (@empty($row["cushions"])) {
$url = "accessories.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
} elseif (!@empty($row["glasstop"])) {
$url = "glasstop.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
} else {
$url = "shopping_cart.php";
}
```

And this for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
  <label for="quantity" style="float: left; width: 75px; margin: 0">COLOUR</label>
  <textarea name="colour" id="colour" style="float: left; height: 80px; width: 250px" >   </textarea>
  <img src="images/spacer.gif" class="clear" style="height: 10px" />
  <input type="submit" value="ADD COLOUR TO ORDER" id="submit" onmouseover="this.style.color = '#DBC87B'" onmouseout="this.style.color = '#FFFFFF'" style="float: left; margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 10px; width: 255px; padding-bottom: 3px; height: 23px" />
  <a href="<?php echo (!@empty($row["cushions"])) ? "shopping_cart.php" : "accessories.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"]?>" style="float: left; color: #251717; background-color: #DBC87B">NO THANKYOU, PROCEED WITH ORDER</a>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["id"]?>" />
</form>
```

So between the two it can't be far off, but I'm a little out of my depth with the syntax which obviously has to be exactly right.

---

The issue is obviously to do with the code in the link in the form. If the original is:

```
<a href="<?php echo (!@empty($row["cushions"])) ? "shopping_cart.php" : "accessories.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"]?>">NO THANK YOU, PROCEED WITH ORDER</a>
```

And that is saying:

If 'cushions' is not empty then go to shopping_cart.php, otherwise go to accessories.php.

Can that be changed to say:

If 'cushions' = -1 then go to accessories.php, If 'cushions2 = -1 then go to accessories2.php, otherwise go to shopping_cart.php?

To match the logic in the header, which works correctly when the form submit button is pressed:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$_SESSION["basket"]["items"][$_POST["id"]]["paintwork"] = $_POST["colour"];
if ($row["cushions"] == -1) {
    $url = "accessories.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
} else if ($row["cushions2"] == -1) {
    $url = "accessories2.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
} else {
    $url = "shopping_cart.php";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the conditional code is working, because the href tag is not being set, that is why it is just reloading the page? Also this code if (!empty($_POST)) { seems to be missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Its working on the submit button, i.e. if you type a colour and click on 'Add Colour to Order'. But not working for the <a href> where you click on No Thank You.

Comment: That is because your PHP code has no idea what that href link is. Remember that PHP is server-side and HTML (your link) is client-side. The $url is not getting set because it is encapsulated by your if (!empty($_POST)) { code. That is link is meant to send you to shopping_cart.php when No Thank You is clicked right?

Comment: No - that link should go to accessories.php if cushions = -1, or go to accessories2.php if cushions2 = -1. It should only go to shopping_cart.php if neither cushions or cushions2 = -1. It should be subject to the same criteria as the Add Colour button. Is that going to be possible?

Comment: Try taking your if then else code out of the $_POST if statement so that you detect and set the $url var.

Comment: If I do that, it works with the No thank you link, but stops working with the Add Colour button.

Comment: The original was a little different, and simpler with just the one cushion option:

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if (!@empty($_POST)) {
  $_SESSION["basket"]["items"][$_POST["id"]]["paintwork"] = $_POST["colour"];
  if (@empty($row["cushions"])) {
    $url = "accessories.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
  // uncomment these 2 lines for Glass Top functionality
  } elseif (!@empty($row["glasstop"])) {
    $url = "glasstop.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
  } else {
    $url = "shopping_cart.php";
  }

Comment: And for the form submit and link:

Comment: <input type="submit" value="ADD COLOUR TO ORDER" id="submit" onmouseover="this.style.color = '#DBC87B'" onmouseout="this.style.color = '#FFFFFF'" style="float: left; margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 10px; width: 255px; padding-bottom: 3px; height: 23px" />
      <a href="<?php echo (!@empty($row["cushions"])) ? "shopping_cart.php" : "accessories.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"]?>" style="float: left; color: #251717; background-color: #DBC87B">NO THANKYOU, PROCEED WITH ORDER</a>

Comment: So between the two it can't be far off, but I'm a little out of my depth with the syntax which obviously has to be exactly right.

Comment: Edit your question if you want to post code. Otherwise add your comments to my answer.

Comment: Sorry - edited it above now.

Answer (score 1):

`if (!empty($_POST)) { ...}` means if the POST is not empty do ... right? So, the link:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url?>" style="float: left; color: #251717; background-color: #DBC87B">NO    THANKYOU, PROCEED WITH ORDER</a>
```

is not an actual POST but rather is just a link. Thus the code:

> if (!empty($_POST)) {
>
> ```
> $_SESSION["basket"]["items"][$_POST["id"]]["paintwork"] = $_POST["colour"];
>
> if ($row["cushions"] == -1) {
>     $url = "accessories.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
> } else if ($row["cushions2"] == -1) {
>     $url = "accessories2.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
> } else if (!empty($row["glasstop"])) {
>     $url = "glasstop.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"];
> } else {
>     $url = "shopping_cart.php";
>
> } }
> ```

never fires off and $url is never set because $_POST is empty, giving you an empty $url variable and link thereby reloading the page.

You may want to try:

```
if ($row["cushions"] == -1) {    
  $url = "accessories.php?id=" .
  $_REQUEST["id"]; 
} else if ($row["cushions2"] == -1) {
  $url ="accessories2.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"]; 
} else if(!empty($row["glasstop"])) {
  $url = "glasstop.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"]; } else {
  $url = "shopping_cart.php"; 
}
```

> if (!empty($_POST)) {
>
> ```
> $_SESSION["basket"]["items"][$_POST["id"]]["paintwork"] = $_POST["colour"];
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Thanks - with that it forwards automatically to accessories.php or accessories2.php from paintwork.php.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I have this working now. I had a bit of an epiphany in that I could wrap three links in a bit of conditional code which would work:

```
<?php if ($row['cushions']=="0" AND $row['cushions2']=="0"){ ?>
  <a href="shopping_cart.php" style="float: left; color: #251717; background-color: #DBC87B">NO THANK YOU, PROCEED WITH ORDER</a><br>
  <?php }  ?>
  <?php if ($row['cushions']=="-1"){ ?>
  <a href="<?php echo "accessories.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"]?>" style="float: left; color: #251717; background-color: #DBC87B">NO THANK YOU, PROCEED WITH ORDER</a><br>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php  if ($row['cushions2']=="-1"){ ?>
  <a href="<?php echo "accessories2.php?id=" . $_REQUEST["id"]?>" style="float: left; color: #251717; background-color: #DBC87B">NO THANK YOU, PROCEED WITH ORDER</a><br>
  <?php } ?>
```

Its not as elegant as it might be, but it seems to work!